# How to use multiple angular material sideNav bars in same side?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have 5 buttons for sideNav bars in left side. What I wanted to do is when I click one button sidebar is coming but when I click another button another side bar should come and previous one should automatically close

Here is my code :

**HTML**

```
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container" autosize>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="actions">
      <div (click)="drawer1.toggle()"></div>
      <div (click)="drawer2.toggle()"></div>
      <div (click)="drawer3.toggle()"></div>
      <div (click)="drawer4.toggle()"></div>
      <div (click)="drawer5.toggle()"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <mat-drawer #drawer1 class="example-sidenav" mode="over">
        <p>A</p>
      </mat-drawer>

      <mat-drawer #drawer2 class="example-sidenav" mode="over">
        <p>B</p>
      </mat-drawer>

      <mat-drawer #drawer3 class="example-sidenav" mode="over">
        <p>C</p>
      </mat-drawer>

      <mat-drawer #drawer4 class="example-sidenav" mode="over">
        <p>D</p>
      </mat-drawer>

      <mat-drawer #drawer5 class="example-sidenav" mode="over">
        <p>E</p>
      </mat-drawer>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

**Style.SCSS**

```
.mat-drawer-backdrop.mat-drawer-shown {
  background-color: unset !important;
}

.mat-drawer { //locate the side bar under the button
  z-index: -1 !important;
  width: 90%;
}

.mat-drawer-inner-container { //make the container text 
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 140px;
}
```

Here is the

> [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-sidenav-fqyoah?file=styles.scss)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, you will need to toggle a sidenav and manually close the others, just give each sidenav an `id`, and use that `div` with the `click` event to toggle the specified sidenav and close the others.

Here's an edited version of you [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-sidenav-vq9ve3?file=app%2Fsidenav%2Fsidenav.component.html) as a running example.